# Swift Firebase TableView Data - DataEventType.value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing a call into a child "following" and am seeing if the logged-in user's UID is there and has a child of another user which the logged-in user is following.

I am printing who the logged-in user is following into a tableview. The first problem is my code, because I know it is bad practice to have two firebase calls within each other so I need someone to teach me a better method. Because of the poor code, when I go unfollow the other user and come back to the tab where the logged-in users list of who they are following is displayed it shows this (image below). When the logged-in user is following nobody it should just display the "Sorry!" text, yet still keeps who the user was following. Need someone to teach me a better method for doing this type of firebase call. Code and a firebase JSON stack image are below... In the firebase JSON stack image, the expanded UID is the logged-in user and the child in is the other user the logged-in user is following. I need a better way to call and extract this information, I am just ignorant of how-to.

[image]

[image]

```
func getFollowingData() {

    Database.database().reference().child("following").child(uid!).observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            print("Got Snapshot")
            Database.database().reference().child("following").child(self.uid!).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                if snapshot.exists() {
                    print(snapshot)
                    let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    self.listFollowing.append(snapshot)
                    self.followingTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.listFollowing.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
                    self.followingTableView.backgroundView = nil
                }
            })
        } else {
            print("No Snapshot")
            self.followingTableView.backgroundView = self.noDataView
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: "it is bad practice to have two firebase calls within each other" Why do you think that is a bad practice? I'm not saying it isn't btw, but I'd like to see the reasoning before accepting it as a blanket statement.

Comment: I've just been told that but they can be wrong and gave me bad information

Comment: OK. So in that case let's focus on the code. When you run the snippet you shared, what is the problem with that code?

Comment: The problem is that the tableview needs to get reloaded after the user goes and unfollows someone making the tableview empty and showing the backgroundView. Currently, its like the picture I posted but when I go back and follow again and go back to the following list, there are now repeating cells of the user

Comment: I've tried doing a .removeAll as well as a viewWillAppear, but none has been working.

Comment: I've done implementation like this before yet, haven't had it to where I am trying to query a UID key and ask to see if it matches the current user. I am not even sure this can be done

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I just decided to do it how I did it on other feeds on my project

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, just needed to do it how I did it before on other feeds.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class BusinessFollowing: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var noDataView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var followingTableView: UITableView!

var yourFollowing = [Information]()

var listFollowing = [NSDictionary?]()
var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid


var loggedInUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
var loggedInUserData:NSDictionary?

var following = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.followingTableView.backgroundView = nil


}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.followingTableView.reloadData()
    self.yourFollowing.removeAll()
    self.following.removeAll()

    getFollowingData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    if segue.identifier == "following" {
        // gotta check if we're currently searching
            if let indexPath = followingTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let user = listFollowing[indexPath.row]
                let controller = segue.destination as? ExploreBusinessProfileSwitchView
                controller?.otherUser = user
            }
    }
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return self.yourFollowing.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! BusinessFollowingCell
    let following = yourFollowing[indexPath.row]

    let businessName = following.businessName
    let businessStreet = following.businessStreet
    let businessCity = following.businessCity
    let businessState = following.businessState

    cell.businessName.text = businessName
    cell.businessStreet.text = businessStreet
    cell.businessCity.text = businessCity
    cell.businessState.text = businessState

    // cell.businessName?.text = self.listFollowing[indexPath.row]?["businessName"] as? String
    // cell.businessStreet?.text = self.listFollowing[indexPath.row]?["businessStreet"] as? String
    // cell.businessCity?.text = self.listFollowing[indexPath.row]?["businessCity"] as? String
    // cell.businessState?.text = self.listFollowing[indexPath.row]?["businessState"] as? String

    return cell
}

func getFollowingData() {
    self.yourFollowing.removeAll()
    self.following.removeAll()
    self.followingTableView.reloadData()

    Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!).child("following").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
            let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
            databaseRef.child("Businesses").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (usersSnapshot) in
                let users = usersSnapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                for (_, value) in users {
                    if let userID = value["uid"] as? String {
                        if userID == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                            print(value)
                            if let followingUsers = value["following"] as? [String : String] {
                                for (_,user) in followingUsers {
                                    self.following.append(user)
                                }
                            }
                            databaseRef.child("following").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (postsSnapshot) in
                                let posts = postsSnapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

                                for (_, post) in posts {
                                    for (_, postInfo) in post as! [String: AnyObject] {
                                        if let followingID = postInfo["uid"] as? String {
                                            for each in self.following {
                                                if each == followingID {
                                                    guard let uid = postInfo["uid"] as! String? else {return}
                                                    guard let name = postInfo["businessName"] as! String? else {return}
                                                    guard let address = postInfo["businessStreet"] as! String? else {return}
                                                    guard let state = postInfo["businessState"] as! String? else {return}
                                                    guard let city = postInfo["businessCity"] as! String? else {return}

                                                    self.yourFollowing.append(Information(uid: uid, businessName: name, businessStreet: address, businessCity: city, businessState: state))
                                                }

                                                self.followingTableView.backgroundView = nil
                                                self.followingTableView.reloadData()
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                            }) { (error) in
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            })
        } else {
            print("Not following anyone")
            self.followingTableView.backgroundView = self.noDataView
            MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
        }
    })

}

}
```